# Facing issue while POST when it has no payload (python code)

Tags: python, api, post

The code called by my script is (this is code in api.py)

```
def post(url, data=None, **kwargs):
    """Sends a POST request. Returns :class:`Response` object.

    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    """
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
```

Now I need to POST a request which has no payload, as the info which I need to post is in url itself. I have tried following combinations but failed:

1) `requests.post(url, auth, data=None)`

Fails saying:

```
result = requests.post(api, auth, data=None)
TypeError: post() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'
```

2) `requests.post(api, auth, data=payload)` where payload is empty json.

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passed auth param is accepted by function as data one. Then you passed data again, as keyword argument.

```
result = requests.post(api, auth, data=None)
TypeError: post() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'
```

Try this:

```
result = requests.post(api, auth=auth)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the incompatibility between the method signature and how you call it.

```
def post(url, data=None, **kwargs):
result = requests.post(api, auth, data=None)
```

First of all, based on the error, its save to assume `requests` is a library you've written (and not the Python requests module), and not a class because you'd get a completely different error otherwise.

Your `post` method has 2 arguments, `url` and `data`.

Your call has three arguments, which python has to unpack: the variables `api` and `auth` and a named argument of `data=None`.

Python assigns `api` to the `url` variable in the methods scope, and `auth` to the `data` variable. This leaves an extra named `data` variable in the methods scope, which now is attempting to be assigned again.

Hence the error:

```
post() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'
```